# Escaping colon in mysql LIKE query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql query which searches for a specific word. For example lets make a search for Killzone Shadow Fall(stored in a variable):

```
select * from games where title like 'Killzone Shadow Fall'
```

It returns empty. Though this entry exist in the database as 'Killzone: Shadow Fall'

What should be done in order to return 'Killzone: Shadow Fall' when someone searches for 'Killzone Shadow Fall'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape colon, try changing to:

```
select * from games where title like 'Killzone%'
```

This will return all records from table where `title` field's value starts with `Killzone`.

Comment: Ahhh I see.. I had it before and after the search value. Thanks it works now :)

Comment: It needed a bit more modification though. All I had to do was replace white spaces with %

Comment: Problem with this method is if an user searches for "Halo 5", it'd return all records staring with Halo

Comment: Yes to fix that, I replaced the spaces with %

Answer (score 0):

The `_` character in LIKE replaces only 1 character in a string :

```
select * from games where title like 'Killzone_ Shadow Fall'
```

But it would be preferable to use `%` to have a larger set of occurence matching your search.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest replacing " " with %.

```
$searchTerm = "Killzone Shadow Fall';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM games WHERE title LIKE "'.str_replace(' ','%',$searchTerm).'"';
```